# ModuleNotFoundError when running imported Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, module

I have a python module with the following layout:

```
 foo
  |  __init__.py
  |  __main__.py
  |  bar.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

Content of `foo/bar.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
def baz(): pass
```

When running `python3 -m foo` i get confusing results.

Contents of `foo/__main__.py`

```
# Results in a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
from foo.bar import app
app.run()

# Raises no error and correctly prints the type
from foo.bar import app
print(type(app))

# Also runs without an error
from foo.bar import baz
baz()
```

Why is it possible to import and execute a function from this module, but when trying to do the same with a flask app it results in a `ModuleNotFoundError`?
I just can't see any way this makes any sense.

Edit:

The error is persistent even with this code:

```
from foo.bar import app

print(type(app))
app.run()
```

Output:

```
<class 'flask.app.Flask'>
 * Serving Flask app "foo.bar" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/ftest/foo/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.bar import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

So, obviously the module **can** be imported, because `type(app)` works just fine and flask **does start**. It seems like flask does a reload and is messing around with imports somehow.

Edit 2:

I turned debug mode off and it works just fine.
This error only occurs if you set `export FLASK_DEBUG=True` or explicitly enable debug via `app.config["DEBUG"] = True`

Comment: I recreated your project but don't see the error, nor can I see any reason for it in your code. Are you sure this is the code and layout that you use? Is your `__init__.py` empty or does it contain code? Where are you running the command from?

Comment: re "why is it possible": Flask does something special about the argument; for instance, if I do `app = Flask("qux.baz")`, I get a failure because module `qux` doesn't exist. So my guess here is that either you are passing something strange to it, or maybe something messy, like you have left-over `__pycache__` that got locked with a bad name somehow...

Comment: @matejcik: `__init__.py` is empty, i updated the question to add this info. I'm running the code from the directory above. I cleaned `__pycache__`, that doesn't help. I'm not doing anything strange at all, because what's in the post is literally all the code in the module.

Comment: are you sure you were in the good directory when you executed the first `__main__.py` code? (maybe add `import os;print(os.getcwd())` on top  to check )

Comment: @PRMoureu it's all executed from the same directory.

Comment: and what happens if you mix the first and second code ? `print(type(app))
` before `app.run()`. Please add the full traceback error

Comment: @PRMoureu I updated the post and included the terminal output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it's a bug in werkzeug.
The code works as expected if werkzeug's reloader is disabled.

**How to reproduce the behaviour**

Directory structure:

```
 foo
  |  __init__.py
  |  __main__.py
```

Content of `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
```

Content of `__main__.py`:

```
from foo import app
app.run()
```

If we run it:

```
$python3 -m foo
 * Serving Flask app "foo" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/ftest/foo/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

If we change `__main__.py`:

```
from foo import app
app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

Everything works just fine.

**What's going on**

The problem is in `werkzeug._reloader.ReloaderLoop.restart_with_reloader`. It calls a subprocess with the arguments provided by `werkzeug._reloader._get_args_for_reloading` but this function does not behave as expected when executing a package via the `-m` switch.

```
def _get_args_for_reloading():
    """Returns the executable. This contains a workaround for windows
    if the executable is incorrectly reported to not have the .exe
    extension which can cause bugs on reloading.
    """
    rv = [sys.executable]
    py_script = sys.argv[0]
    if os.name == 'nt' and not os.path.exists(py_script) and \
       os.path.exists(py_script + '.exe'):
        py_script += '.exe'
    if os.path.splitext(rv[0])[1] == '.exe' and os.path.splitext(py_script)[1] == '.exe':
        rv.pop(0)
    rv.append(py_script)
    rv.extend(sys.argv[1:])
    return rv
```

In our case it returns `['/usr/local/bin/python3.7', '/home/user/projects/ftest/foo/__main__.py']`. This is because `sys.argv[0]` is set to the full path of the module file but it should return ['/usr/local/bin/python3.7', '-m', 'foo']` (At least from my understanding it should and it works this way).

I have no good idea on how to fix this behaviour, or if it is something that need to be fixed. It just seems weird to me that I'm the only one that has encountered this problem, since it doesn't seem too much of a corner case to me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line before app.run() works around the werkzeug reloader bug:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.getcwd()
```

Thanks to @bootc for the tip! https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1246

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried from foo import app in your main.py file?

Comment: I did, see my solution in the pagragraph about reproducing the behaviour.

Comment: Have you set PYTHONPATH?

Comment: More info over here, seems to look like your issue? https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1246

Comment: This is indeed the same issue, but it seems like the guys at werkzeug don't see any reasonable way to fix this either. But at least I've got a workaround now. Thanks!